# Gremlin and Indices

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I've been using indices these days and I noticed that if I make an indexed key on `dmdid` the following query is fast:

```
graph.query().has("firstname", "Joan").has("lastname", "Dupont").vertices()
```

This one also is fast:

```
new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertices("firstname", "Joan")).has("lastname", "Dupont").cast(classOf[Vertex]).toList()
```

But this one is slow as if I've no indexing:

```
new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertices()).has("firstname", "Joan").has("lastname", "Dupont").cast(classOf[Vertex]).toList()
```

I think my question is split in 2 parts (or 3):

- First the ability to optimise the query of the **start Vertices** seems to be impossible if I have to filter on 2 indexed key (here first and last name)?
- Second the ability to optimise **traversal of a graph** via Pipelines seems to not work?
- The 2 first concepts seems to be completely separated although they seems to face the same issue. To me getting all vertices and filtering on them (the last example) should be the same as the 2 first ones because the query is executed on the DB, don't you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that your last query will support the optimization.  Picking apart your query:

```
new GremlinPipeline(graph.getVertices()).has("dmdid", id).has("type", type).cast(classOf[Vertex]).toList()
```

You are feeding all the vertices in the graph into the pipeline which them iterates them out into the `has` where your index is.  As such, the rest of the pipeline starting with that `has` treats it as a linear scan.  Gremlin can't compile down the query properly as it doesn't have knowledge of the entire thing.

What you can do with indices is very much tied to the underlying graph.  The graph implementation says a lot about how the optimization will occur. Regarding,

> First the ability to optimise the query of the start Vertices seems to
>   be impossible if I have to filter on 2 indexed key (here first and
>   last name)?

Getting "start vertices" with a key index in the Blueprints-sense, the generalized approach would be to create a composite key combining first and last name to one property.  Regarding,

> Second the ability to optimise traversal of a graph via Pipelines seems to not work?

You don't say what graph database you are using, but not all graphs will support pushing down `has` operations to the database.  Titan does the best job of taking advantage of such things and will take advantage of [vertex centric indices](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices) wherever they can be found in the gremlin expression.  Regarding:

> The 2 first concepts seems to be completely separated although they
>   seems to face the same issue. To me getting all vertices and filtering
>   on them (the last example) should be the same as the 2 first ones
>   because the query is executed on the DB, don't you think so?

As you probably gathered from my previous statement, your query is not executed on the DB.  Gremlin is not compiled to some expression that the every graph database understands and can optimize.  Gremlin is groovy code that operates over Blueprints.  Some graph databases (like Titan and OrientDB to some degree) are capable of optimizing the traversals based on their implementation.  As I mentioned above, Titan will take advantage of vertex centric indices where possible to limit what data is processed in memory by Gremlin.  Such optimizations can lead to good [performance improvements](http://thinkaurelius.com/2012/10/25/a-solution-to-the-supernode-problem/).

Comment: So if we assume what you say, it means that indices are used ONLY on one key to find the entry point and indices are NOT used at any time while traversing the graph? This sounds impossible to use in big graphs.

Comment: I think there are two topics here; 1st is whether your last query should support optimization. The 2nd is a more general assertion that once we have a starting point for a query we still need to be able to use the index to hop around the graph (rather than follow links to other points in the graph). Do I have that 2nd part right? If so, what is the use case? Do you expect to find just one vertex via exact match or are you looking for a collection of items? Is it something that should be linked in stead? Thanks. (I have been thinking there could be use for an idx pipe.)

Comment: You are right @Paul Jackson I edited my question to chunk it in some points as you specify.  
My questions is general to how it works (retrieving an exact vertex or a collection).  
`idx` is for manual indices sand I'm using automatic indices.

Comment: i updated my answer bit. you didn't say what graph database you were using, but i think my answer generally applies.

Comment: i'd also add that titan has additional options for doing "composite indices" through integration with external indexing backends: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Indexing-Backend-Overview for returning large collections of vertices, that might be a useful approach, if Titan is your database.

Comment: So you mean that every time I update a property apart of the composite, I will have to update also the composite index? Or there is some settings to maintain composite indices automatically?
Because the query is optimised only on the first index on my tests (no matter if the second one is indexed or not)

Comment: Yes, under that approach, you would manually maintain your composite index such that you would update that "fullName" property whenever the first or last name properties were changed.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think any graphs support a true composite index in the same way that relational databases do.  I just did a quick check of the major graphdbs that have Blueprints implementations and I didn't see that functionality anywhere.  This pattern of manually maintaining a "composite" property is pretty common I think.

Comment: That's tedious... Hop that we would see an automatic optimisation feature that we can activate like automatic indexing in Titan.

Comment: If you really hate the idea of doing it manually, a trick would be to build a custom Blueprint `WrapperGraph` (examples of other wrappers would be `ReadOnlyGraph`, `PartitionGraph`, etc) that detects modifications to properties related to composite keys then automates the update to the composite key itself.  That probably wouldn't be too hard to implement.  At least then your logic for indices would be hidden and centralized to a single place.

Comment: That's a good idea. So I would conclude that there is solutions but there is still improvements that can be done especially on the `has()` statements after a `getVertices()`, that should be optimised. And some auto composite indices. If I'm right.

Comment: Titan 0.5.x supports "composite" indices - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/cNb4fKoe95M